# Mathematica: converting output from Cluster[]

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, cluster-analysis

Imagine a data set like this:

> {{{1,2},{3,4}},{{8,8},{3,7},{5,2}}}.

Note that at the top level this list has `{{1,2},{3,4}}` as the first element and `{{8,8},{3,7},{5,2}}` as the second.

Using that fact, the desired output would be:

> {{1,2,1},{3,4,1},{8,8,2},{3,7,2},{5,2,2}}

I have already tried using `Map[]`.

This arose because I was using cluster analysis which gave me a list, rather than an indexing of various clusters. I did not find an option in `Cluster[]` to do this directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
In[1]:= v = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{8, 8}, {3, 7}, {5, 2}}};
   Flatten[Table[Map[Join[#, {i}] &, v[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[v]}], 1]

Out[1]= {{1, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 1}, {8, 8, 2}, {3, 7, 2}, {5, 2, 2}}
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if it was not just code but also included some descriptive text that says _why_ it is a solution (or _how_ you worked it out, or… well anything to make it not just text really!)

Comment: Ok, I can be agreeable. He provided the exact input in Mathematica form, thank you, and the exact desired output in same, thank you. He wanted to add an element to the ends of lists, so Join was the first thought. He then wanted to append the same element to the end of every list so Map was the second thought. He then wanted to do this to a collection of items so Table with subscripting was the third thought. And finally that left some extra layers of list nesting so Flatten was added as an afterthought. All that was executed in a single step to show it did exactly what he asked for in his q..

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about the conversion, using the steps as they naturally come to mind.

```
v = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{8, 8}, {3, 7}, {5, 2}}};
```

Note the result obtained using `MapIndexed` :-

```
MapIndexed[{#1, First[#2]} &, v]
```

> {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 1}, {{{8, 8}, {3, 7}, {5, 2}}, 2}}

To append the part specs (1 & 2) to the subelements I would use `MapThread`.  This requires multiple part specs, e.g. `{2, 2, 2}` for element 2 :-

```
MapThread[Append, {{{8, 8}, {3, 7}, {5, 2}}, {2, 2, 2}}]
```

> {{8, 8, 2}, {3, 7, 2}, {5, 2, 2}}

So the `MapIndexed` expression is modified to produce the necessary part specs :-

```
MapIndexed[{#1, ConstantArray[First[#2], Length[#1]]} &, v]
```

> {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {1, 1}}, {{{8, 8}, {3, 7}, {5, 2}}, {2, 2, 2}}}

Now `MapThread` can be used in the `MapIndexed` expression :-

```
MapIndexed[MapThread[Append, {#1, ConstantArray[First[#2], Length[#1]]}] &, v]
```

> {{1, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 1}}, {{8, 8, 2}, {3, 7, 2}, {5, 2, 2}}}

Finally, the first list level is flattened :-

```
Flatten[MapIndexed[MapThread[Append,
    {#1, ConstantArray[First[#2], Length[#1]]}] &, v], 1]
```

> {{1, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 1}, {8, 8, 2}, {3, 7, 2}, {5, 2, 2}}

Comment: how about applying `MapIndexed` to level 2?

Comment: @george - good point. `Flatten[MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #1, First[#2]} &, v, {2}], 1]`